# What exactly is the "tonic sol–fa" system, and how is it different from solfège?

Tags: solfege

I'm fluent in both fixed- and movable-do solfège, but I'm wondering how the "tonic sol–fa" system

- overlaps with fixed- and movable-do solfège, and
- offers something new that fixed- and movable-do solfège cannot.

I'd especially love an answer with a musical example that shows the difference between one of those two solfège systems and the "tonic sol–fa" system.

Comment: If you are familiar with other solfège systems, you might as well go to straight to the source: https://archive.org/details/cu31924021797547. It's only about 35 pages long. Or look at the original standard textbook for teaching it (10 times as long): https://archive.org/details/standardcourseof00curwuoft

Comment: Isn't tonic sol-fa the same as movable-do solfege? As far as I am aware, tonic sol-fa uses the root note as do, as movable do solfege does, whereas fixed do, as common in France and others will only recognise C as do, and no other.

Comment: Oh dear, it is not just movable do.  It is a way of combining movable do first letters with rhythm using a full-ish notation system written without a staff.  Ugh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are no answers and because alephzero's comment helped clarify everything for me, I'll take the liberty of writing my own. This information comes from the manual alephzero provided [here](https://archive.org/details/cu31924021797547). (I didn't even think to look here, so thanks!)

### Overview

The tonic sol–fa system is really more a system of *notation* than it is a solfège system. So while the system uses solfège syllables (and abbreviations of them), tonic sol–fa functions as a notation system complete with rhythm and meter.

### Comparisons with Fixed- and Movable-Do Solfège

Tonic sol–fa is a movable do system; tonic is always "doh," the dominant scale degree is always "sol," and so on. The syllable for the leading tone is "te" (pronounced "tee"). (Most systems I see write the leading tone as "ti," the third as "mi," but tonic sol–fa has chosen the "-e" ending.) With that said, these diatonic pitches are only notated by their first initial: "doh" is "d," "sol" is "s," etc. And since it is a movable system, the key is always given at the start.

Raised pitches end in this "-e" vowel, so scale-degrees 6–♯6–7 are "l–le–t" ("lah–lee–tee"). Lowered pitches end in "-a", so 3–♭3–2 is "m–ma–r." Note that we notate the full syllable for chromatic pitches.

In contrast to solfège, tonic sol–fa specifies register by using `'` or `,` to the right of the pitches to move them an octave higher or lower.

### Notation

But the real difference is in how this system notates metered music. In tonic sol–fa, a weak beat is preceded by a `:`, a medium accent is preceded by `|`, and the downbeat is preceded by nothing (but note that barlines are occasionally inserted), so a measure of 4/4 time would be:

```
    Key E
    d :r |m :ma
```

If you need a little test, this notation translates to:

> E F♯ G♯ G♮

More specifics about metered notation can be found in Chapter III of the manual linked at the top of this answer.

Ultimately, tonic sol–fa notation produces notation such as

[image]

The decision of whether this is a worthwhile substitute for notation, or if it is worth the time to teach, is of course up to the individual teacher.

Comment: The lowered pitches (flat notes) are said to rhyme with 'aw'. It's an interesting concept, which didn't take off too well, due in part to Dr. J Hullah, the new gov't inspector of music at teacher training colleges, who had just brought the fixed do concept across from France, and unsurprisingly, he championed that from 1872.

Comment: Can you notate pauses or non quarter notes?

Comment: @Francesco Apparently so. The explanation is a bit too much for a comment, and I'm not currently in a good position to write it out as an edit to my question, so I'll refer you to pages 6–10 of the PDF linked at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: China has something similar called jianpu - 1-7 for notes of the major key (minor starts on 6), dots above and below for octaves, and the standard sharp and flat signs for chromatic notes.