# Arthur Somervell: 1000 Exercises - Meaning of this notation

Tags: notation, voice, sight-reading

Arthur Somervell's uses the following notation on his *One Thousand Exercises*

[image]

Is it a standard notation? What's the meaning?

Comment: Just a guess: all the letters are the first letters of the solfege syllables, *do re mi fa sol la ti*, so perhaps that’s what the letters refer to at least.

Comment: I was thinking about it. Maybe it's 2/4 time signature and **d'** is do sharp

Comment: d’ = upper do, sharps ans flats are shown in the notes and. It’s a movemable do re mi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the "tonic sol–fa" system. Created by a guy named [John Curwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Curwen), it's not exactly a singing system like solfège, but rather a *notation* system.

At the risk of publicizing myself, I asked (and subsequently answered) a question on this exact distinction at [What exactly is the "tonic sol–fa" system, and how is it different from solfège?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58015/21766)

Answer (score 4):

[image]This standard solfege notation in certain English songbook editions: the letters are abbreviations of the doremi syllables.

There are also symbols for the note length.

I have to assume:

: = next beat. - = tied quarter

d’ = do hihgher octave

t, = lower ti

Comment: The sheet music explains itself the meaning of the signs.